# Validation not working on Ranges?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Can someone explain to me why my validation won't get triggered when I submit a string such as "foo" to `number`?

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :number, :inclusion => 0..100

end
```

Only when I change my code to this...

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :number, :inclusion  => 0..100, :numericality => true

end
```

... the validation gets triggered.

Is this a Rails bug or am I missing something really fundamental here?

I am using Rails 4.2.0 by the way.

Comment: I guess your syntax is incorrect try this:
 validates :number, inclusion: { in: 0..100 }

Comment: Contrary to what I thought `validates :number, inclusion: 0..100` _is_ valid syntax. Rails converts a Range or Array value to an `:in` value in the options key.

Answer (score 1):

It's because rails is converting the string to a number (assuming you've got it persisted as an integer) before doing the validation. If you call `to_i` on a string you get `0` which is valid for your range.

For example:

```
> c = Course.new
> c.number = 'hi'
> c.number
=> 0
> c.valid?
=> true
```

The reason the numericality validators is triggering when you add it is, I think, because it checks the value before any type casting happens:

```
> c.number = 'hi'
> c.number_before_type_cast
=> 'hi'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think you're absolutely right here.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
validates_numericality_of :number, :only_integer => true, 
 :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1,
 :less_than_or_equal_to => 99,
 :message => "can only be number between 1 and 100."
```

ref: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_numericality_of

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to work best for me:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :number, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => 100 }

end
```